# Find the minimal polynomial of -10-3i over the reals

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

First of all, I apologize for posting this question as I feel it is entirely a routine computation homework problem that I have adequate information from my text book to solve and verify on my own. That said, the reason I am turning to MSE with this is because this question is part of an 'online homework' I am doing, and I am convinced I have proven that my answer is correct and the online homework system continues to tell me I am wrong. I am getting quite furious as I really just want to get this assignment over with, and I believe my answer is correct!

I just want to get some verification before I email the professor complaining about faulty software. After all, it is possible I am making a careless mistake somewhere.

> Question: Find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = -10-3i$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Solution:

**Step 1: Find $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0.$**

Clearly $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x) = (x+10)^2 + 9$. Expanding this out we get $f(x) = x^2 +20x +109$. This polynomial is monic and evaluating we see $f(\alpha) = 0$.

**Step 2: Confirm $f(x)$ is irreducible.**

Since $f$ has degree 2 and is over a field, it suffices to confirm $f$ has not roots in $\mathbb{R}$. An application of the quadratic equation shows a negative discriminant which confirms $f(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $f(x)$ is a irreducible monic polynomial containing $\alpha$ as a root, by uniqueness this is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

*Have I made a careless mistake? Have I misread a definition? Or should I begin an email to my professor about faulty software?*

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha agrees with you](http://bit.ly/2q3P88U).  In my experience when the students mathematically correct answer is marked incorrect, the most likely source is interface mismatch.  Like, the form expects an expression and the student writes an equation.  Or (less often), the student enters variables in uppercase.  Have a face-to-face with the professor to suss out the mistake.  If it really is a bug, it's probably not the professor's fault.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know Wolfram had software for minimal polynomials. I also suspected it was formatting causing the issue, but I entered the polynomial in the same format as all the other minimal polynomial questions, so I'm not sure what is the issue. And yes! I am not blaming the professor for the issue, I just wanted to make sure there was not a mistake on my end before claiming faulty software and embarrassing myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No your solution is correct

Also since you cannot have a $1$-degree equation in $R$ for which $\alpha$ is a root and you have a $2$-degree polynomial in $R$ such that $\alpha$ is a root hence the polynomial is automatically minimal, you may not go into any other details as the minimal polynomial is a polynomial of least possible degree.